# Is there a simple property to make this proof a one-liner?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

For some functions $g(x) \geq 0$ and $f(x)$, I want to show that

\begin{equation}
\left( \int_0^\infty f(x) g(x) dx \right)^2 - \int_0^\infty g(x)dx \int_0^\infty f(x)^2 g(x) dx \leq 0 
\end{equation}

I have managed to do so in a sort of convoluted fashion:

\begin{align}
&\left( \int_0^\infty f(x) g(x) dx \right)^2 - \int_0^\infty g(x)dx \int_0^\infty f(x)^2 g(x) dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(x) f(y) g(x) g(y) dx dy - \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(x)^2 g(x) g(y) dx dy \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(x) f(y) g(x) g(y) dx dy - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty (f(x)^2 + f(y)^2) g(x) g(y) dx dy \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty (f(x) - f(y))^2 g(x) g(y) dx dy \leq 0
\end{align}

I'd imagine there might be a simpler, more elegant way, citing some well-known theorem. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't this Cauchy Schwarz with $h_1 = \sqrt{g}$ and $h_2 = f\sqrt{g}$? Cauchy-Schwarz says $(\int h_1h_2)^2 \leq \int h_1^2 \int h_2^2$, now substitute and finish. If CS is not allowed, then what you have done is tantamount to proving CS for this particular substitution, so it's the shortest method.

Comment: I don't think that is convoluted. It looks great to me. It is all identities, so it cannot be any better, you literally lose nothing at each step. Note that the same method you are using here can be used to prove Cauchy--Schwarz. So if you invoke Cauchy--Schwarz, you are internally redoing what you do here, but losing some information.

Comment: BTW, this is the proof of Cauchy--Schwarz using your method that I have in mind: $$\lVert f\rVert^2_2\lVert g \rVert_2^2-\lvert \langle f, g\rangle \rvert^2 = \frac12 \iint \lvert f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x)\rvert^2\, dxdy \ge 0.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Set $$F(x)=f(x)\sqrt{g(x)}\quad \text{and}\quad G(x)=\sqrt{g(x)}.$$
Then $$\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm d x=\int_0^\infty F(x)G(x)\,\mathrm d x.$$
Then, use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Schwarz, not Schwartz.